# shell script to find the number of occurence of particular word from text file

Tags: unix

My file is ss.txt

```
Another instance started
Another instance started 
Another instance started
Another instance started
No instance started
No instance started
No instance started
No instance started
```

If i use shell script program as this

```
#!/bin/sh
t=0
#temp=0
echo "Enter filename"
read f1
if [ -f $f1 ]
then
echo "1.count char,words,lines"
echo "2.particular word to find in file"
echo "3.exit"
echo "Enter ur choice?"
read ch
case $ch in
1) wc -c $f1
   echo "characters"
   wc -w $f1
   echo "words"
   wc -l $f1
   echo "lines" ;;
2) echo "Enter the word whose occurence has to be found"
   read c
   t='echo $f1 | wc -c'
   echo $t ;;
3) exit ;;
esac
else
echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

If i run this code i get the following output 
i could get the option 2 correct that is word occurence is not correct

i get like

```
Enter filename
ss.txt
1.count char,words,lines
2.particular word in file
3.exit
Enter ur choice?
1
180 ss.txt
characters
24 ss.txt
words
8 ss.txt
lines
```

This i get correctly but for choice 2 i get like

```
Enter filename
ss.txt
1.count char,words,lines
2.particular word in file
3.exit
Enter ur choice?
2
Enter the word whose occurence has to be found
Another
0
```

See i get zero here but output should be 4

Answer (score 0):

change from:

```
t='echo $f1 | wc -c'
```

to

```
t=`grep -o "$c" "${f1}"|wc -l`
```

Comment: I tried i get like bb.sh: 28: 4: not found also i get 0 only as answer

Comment: Are you sure, you only change that line, no other changes?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below commands as per your requirement

t=`grep -c "text" "${f1}"` ( -c, --count count of  matching  lines  for  each  input  file)
  or
t=`grep -o "text" "${f1}"` (   -o,Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.)

bcsmc2rtese001 [~/Shell_p]$ grep -c "Another" ss.txt
4
bcsmc2rtese001 [~/Shell_p]$ grep -o "Another" ss.txt
Another
Another
Another
Another

Comment: will the code above works for 17000 lines please reply

Comment: Actually it is the log file in which i am going to try this code and that the log file keeps on running.. will the code work for the running lines

Comment: are you facing any problem ?